# use bash count every word's occurrence in a file

Tags: arrays, bash

i want to count every word's occurrence in a file
but the result is wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash
#usage: count.sh file

declare -a dict

for word in $(cat $1)
do
    if [ ${dict[$word]} == "" ] ;then
        dict[$word]=0
    else
        dict[$word]=$[${dict[$word]} + 1]
    fi
done

for word in ${!dict[@]}
do
    echo $word: ${dict[$word]}
done
```

use the test file below:

```
learning the bash shell
this is second line
this is the last line
```

bash -x count.sh file
get the result:

```
+ declare -a dict
++ cat book
+ for word in '$(cat $1)'
+ '[' '' == '' ']'
+ dict[$word]=0
+ for word in '$(cat $1)'
+ '[' 0 == '' ']'
+ dict[$word]=1
+ for word in '$(cat $1)'
+ '[' 1 == '' ']'
+ dict[$word]=2
+ for word in '$(cat $1)'
+ '[' 2 == '' ']'
+ dict[$word]=3
+ for word in '$(cat $1)'
+ '[' 3 == '' ']'
+ dict[$word]=4
+ for word in '$(cat $1)'
+ '[' 4 == '' ']'
+ dict[$word]=5
+ for word in '$(cat $1)'
+ '[' 5 == '' ']'
+ dict[$word]=6
+ for word in '$(cat $1)'
+ '[' 6 == '' ']'
+ dict[$word]=7
+ for word in '$(cat $1)'
+ '[' 7 == '' ']'
+ dict[$word]=8
+ for word in '$(cat $1)'
+ '[' 8 == '' ']'
+ dict[$word]=9
+ for word in '$(cat $1)'
+ '[' 9 == '' ']'
+ dict[$word]=10
+ for word in '$(cat $1)'
+ '[' 10 == '' ']'
+ dict[$word]=11
+ for word in '$(cat $1)'
+ '[' 11 == '' ']'
+ dict[$word]=12
+ for word in '${!dict[@]}'
+ echo 0: 12 0: 12
```

Comment: @steve no, i am learning bash myself. i just want to solve this problem with bash

Comment: A good idea using the debug trace, now look at what your debug trace is showing you. Why is it increasing the value to the right of `dict[$word]=` by 1 for each word that it is reading? That's not what you want, is it? Also your debug loop at the end is a good idea, but again the output is showing you that your variable naming/assignment/dereferencing is working as your expect. Good luck.

Comment: ok, I admire your attempt. Note that `$[ .... ]` isn't doing what you expect AND that you can reduce your code for increment process to `(( dict[$word]++ ))` ( I think this works in bash, I know for certain it works in ksh). And.. finally, the old-school unix solution for word counts in files i `sort file file2 ... | uniq -c`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `declare -a dict` means that each key is being evaluated to a numeric value, which is then used as an index. That's not what you want, if you're storing things by words. Use `declare -A` instead.

---

Also, `$[ ]` is an exceedingly outdated syntax for math. Even modern POSIX sh supports `$(( ))`, which you should use instead:

```
dict[$word]=$(( ${dict[$word]} + 1 ))
```

or, to take advantage of bash-only math syntax:

```
(( dict[$word]++ ))
```

---

Also, using `for word in $(cat $1)` is broken in several ways:

- It doesn't quote `$1`, so for a filename with spaces, it will split the name into several words and try to open each word as a separate file. To fix only this, you would use `$(cat "$1")` or `$(<"$1")` (which is more efficient, as it doesn't require starting the external program cat).
- It tries to expand the words in the file as globs -- if the file contains `*`, every file in the current directory will be treated as a word.

Instead, use a while loop:

```
while read -r -d' ' word; do
  if [[ -n ${dict[$word]} ]] ; then
    dict[$word]=$(( ${dict[$word]} + 1 ))
  else
    dict[$word]=1
  fi
done <"$1"
```

Comment: it works. the main problem is "declare -A dict". and i learn much from your answer. thank you very much.

Comment: Although `$((...))` (arithmetic expansion) is POSIX, the compound command `((...))` is not.