# Bash: How to count the number of occurrences of a string within a file?

Tags: string, bash, awk, grep

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
dog
cat
dog
dog
fish
cat
```

I'd like to write some kind of code in Bash to make the file formatted like:

```
dog:1
cat:1
dog:2
dog:3
fish:1
cat:2
```

Any idea on how to do this? The file is very large (> 30K lines), so the code should be somewhat fast.

I am thinking some kind of loop...

Like this:

```
while read line; 
     echo "$line" >> temp.txt
     val=$(grep $line temp.txt)
     echo "$val" >> temp2.txt
done < file.txt
```

And then `paste -d ':' file1.txt temp2.txt`

However, I am concerned that this would be really slow, as you're going line-by-line. What do other people think?

Comment: Please show your attempt

Comment: Just updated the original question!

Comment: Yes, it would be really slow and it'd produce incorrect values due to partial matching and it has other issues such as it'd corrupt some input, would behave differently based on the input values and the directory you run it from, etc. See See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use bash count every word's occurrence in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241517/use-bash-count-every-words-occurrence-in-a-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this simple `awk` to do this job for you:

```
awk '{print $0 ":" ++freq[$0]}' file
```

```
dog:1
cat:1
dog:2
dog:3
fish:1
cat:2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
declare -A arr; while read -r line; do ((arr[$line]++)); echo "$line:${arr[$line]}" >> output_file; done < input_file
```

First, declare hash table arr. Then read every line in a for loop and increment the value in the array with the key of the read line. Then echo out the line, followed out by the value in the hashtable. Lastly append into a file 'out'.

Comment: That would take a VERY long time to run for a moderately sized input file (orders of magnitude slower than an equivalent awk script) and just isn't a good application for shell. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

Awk or sed are very powerful but it's not bash, here is the bash variant

```
raw=( $(cat file) ) # read file
declare -A index    # init indexed array

for item in ${raw[@]}; { ((index[$item]++)); } # 1st loop through raw data to count items
for item in ${raw[@]}; { echo $item:${index[$item]}; } # 2nd loop change data
```